# Spring integration +spring data jpa with hibernate batch insert

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We are using Spring Integration and Spring data jpa with hibernate to pull messages from IBM MQ and persisting to Oracle.

Currently, we are reading the messages 1 at a time and persisting them 1 at a time.

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        channel="routingChannel" 
        container="customJmsInContainer" />

<beans:bean id="customJmsInContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="destination" ref="requestQueue" />
    <beans:property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${jms_adapter_concurrent_consumers}" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionListener" ref="exceptionInListener" />
    <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />
</beans:bean>
```

To improve throughput, we want to be able to read 5 messages and then persist them using Hibernate batch feature.

At the moment, only adding the Hibernate property (hibernate.jdbc.batch_size) does not seem to work. In the logs, at the start of the jetty server, we can see that the property is set properly

```
10:30:02.027 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - JDBC batch size: 5
```

but when the persist code runs we can see the log below

```
10:30:22.715 [customJmsInContainer-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch - Executing batch size: 1
```

How should I redesign the read, such that I can now read 5 messages from MQ and then persist them in batch? Still keeping the current transactional attributes, i.e, if an exception happens when processing the 4th message, they are all rolled back.

Cheers
Liby

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not really showing what you are doing, but the log shows that batching is actually used.

I strongly suspect that you have each insert in a separate transaction thus preventing the batching to gather more inserts.

=> Increase the scope of your transaction to include at least 5 inserts.

Comment: The problem that JMS doesn't work that way. Only one message is pulled from the queue per TX. That's really a general purpose of the Messaging: any message in flight should not affect any other messages. They really can be fully unrelated entities and even belong to different users. You can use an aggregator to perform bulk afterwards, but that's already going to be out of JMS transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the response... As you people have mentioned, batch insert is enabled at hibernate layer, but jms transactions happening one by one only and so finally no batch insert to DB.